# Emission factor for Arsenic

Tags: air-pollution, environmental-protection, pollution, air-quality, emissions

What emission factor for natural gas boiler should be used for arsenic other than AP-42?

I need to to calculate emissions from natural gas boiler. What emission factor for arsenic would be the best to use other than present in AP-42?

Comment: Are you looking for an estimate of actual emissions or the allowable limit imposed by regulations?  The first is probably dependent on the source of the gas, and the second is very dependent on where you are, and the type/size of the boiler.

Comment: Is this really earth science, though? Chemistry SE or Engineering SE might be a better fit.